# jQuery: Bind event handlers to all class instances at once vs each individually when instantiated?

Tags: jquery

I am restructuring my code base into an MVC structure using the revealing prototype pattern and i am wondering what the best way to bind event handlers is.  I have a **Thing** and a **ThingManager**. The **ThingManager** instantiates each **thing** and manages how they behave as a group.  The **Thing** handles it's own internal behaviors.  This leaves two options for binding event handlers for the **Thing**.  Although technically the Thing should bind it's own internal events.  jQuery lends it's self to binding them all at once.  This leaves me to wonder which is more efficient in speed and memory. I'm not looking for bench marks here, just generally if there are any advantages/disadvantages to either option.

Option 1) Bind the **Thing**'s event handlers to it's self each time a new one is created:

```
//Thing model
function ThingModel (id){
    this.id = id;

    this.view = new ThingView(this);
    this.ctrl = new ThingCtrl(this, this.view);
}
ThingModel.prototype = function (){
}();

//Thing view
function ThingView (model){
    this.model = model;
    this.$obj = $();
    this.selector = '.thing#'+this.model.id
    this.init();
}
ThingView.prototype = function (){
    function init(){
        var $obj = $('<div>');
        $obj.addClass('thing');
        $obj.attr('id',this.model.id);
        $(document).append($obj);
        this.$obj = $obj;
    }
    return{init:init}
}();

//Thing controller
function ThingCtrl (model, view){
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;
    this.init();
}
ThingCtrl.prototype = function (){
    function init(){
        // this will bind the handler to THIS .thing instance
        $(document).on('click', this.view.selector, function(){
            //do stuff...
        });
    }
    return{init:init}
}();
```

Option 2) Have the **ThingManager** bind event handlers to each **Thing** all at once (just showing controller for brevity).  NOTE: In this scenario the Thing Controller would NOT bind the events:

```
//ThingManager controller
function ThingManagerCtrl (model, view){
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;
    this.init();
}
ThingManagerCtrl.prototype = function (){
    function init(){
        // this will bind the handler to ALL .thing instances
        $(document).on('click', '.thing', function(){
            //do stuff...
        });
    }
    return{init:init}
}();
```

OPTION 3 After @Bart's answer another option comes to mind using direct events which i believe would be essentially the same as option 1 or worse:

```
ThingCtrl.prototype = function (){
    function init(){
        // this will bind the handler to THIS .thing instance directly
        $(this.view.selector).on('click', function(){
            //do stuff...
        });
    }
    return{init:init}
}();
```

CLARIFICATION of the models & question:
Items are added to the dom via ajax calls to an API in batches of 30.  There can potentially be thousands of items in memory at once.  Each item has a large set of controls, methods, and properties.  The ItemManager has its own large set of controls, methods, & properties.  This is why i would like to separate their respective code as much as possible.  How can I achieve separation of controls while maintaining the efficiency of delegated events?

Comment: it's difficult to answer without knowing approximately how many "Things" might exist at once.  If it's a handful, use the former.  If it's hundreds, use the latter, but consider the tradeoff that event delegation performs (slightly?) worse than direct event handling, albeit better for memory.

Comment: Well the Things are delivered via an ajax call to an API in groups of 30.  There could potentially be thousands in memory as long as the user keeps calling for more.  See my clarification at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is the preferred approach and even the jQuery documentation for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) states

> In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be monitored.

Review the section on [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) for more information plus an example.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will check that out now.

Comment: After reading that, i do see the difference between direct & delegated events (ie: when you delegate the event to say $(document) for all .thing elements you will only have one listener bound to one element(document) where in option 1 you would have as many listeners as there were .thing elements.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, MVC controllers may manage more than one model at a time. The key is to identify relationships between objects and stick them in a single "group" or controller. It is hard to tell remotely what each "thing" does and how each relates. However, my vote would be to group them into one controller.

From a memory perspective, the more singleton objects you create the harder the browser has to work.

Comment: So you are saying eliminate the Item Controller and bind all the Item related events in the ItemManager Controller (option 2) which would mean one less controller instance for each Item created?  Memory wise, this should not have much of an impact since the controller's prototype only exists in memory one time and each instance refers to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Bart for pointing me in the right direction!  I believe this is the best solution to the problem.

Given the original 3 options, it seems clear that option 2 is most efficient. Since the listener is bound only once to the document element.  Where option 1 adds some jquery overhead for each .thing element & Option 3 bind's the handler to each instance of .thing.  However, from a code organization stand point.  I would really like for the Thing controls to be separate from the ThingManager controls. With that being said this solves the problem.

```
ThingCtrl.prototype = function (){

    // This will bind the handler to the document element, one time, when the  
    // prototype is created. Since it is a delegated event each new .thing will 
    // be added automatically and we only have one listener in memory for all of
    // the .thing elements.
    $(document).on('click', '.thing', function(){
            //do stuff...
    });

}();
```